# Select first five elements of a div using class

Tags: html, css

The elements inside the `<div>` will be dynamic of type and count.
I need to blur the first five elements.
How can i select first five elements of `.doc-container` class `<div>` no matter what the type is?

I have seen we can use nth:child but they need some element like `li:nth:child(2)` etc.

is there any way for this problem?

```html
<div class="doc-container">
  <p>one</p>
  <h1>two<h1>
  <p>three</p>
  <span>four</span>
  <p>five<p>
  <h3>six</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The simplest version: Iterate over the `.children`s of `.div-container` with a loop and stop after the fifth child.

Comment: by using pure css how can this be possbile?

Comment: Why css only? There are also `javascript` and `jquery` tags.

Comment: Because if you can do with css it's better to use css than jquery or js

Comment: @Sfili_81 Then OP shouldn't add unrelated tags ;)

Comment: ohh..sorry for that guys...thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the formula `-n + 5`, which means "the fifth element and below". With the `>` selector you select only the direct descendants of the parent. With `*:nth-child` you select every child element regardless of type.

```css
.doc-container > *:nth-child(-n + 5) {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="doc-container">
  <p>one</p>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <p>three</p>
  <span>four</span>
  <p>five</p>
  <h3>six</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah...in place of selector type..just put *...nice ...worked fine..thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the first two elements, try this

```css
.doc-container > :nth-child(-n+2){
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="doc-container">
   <p>one</p>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <p>three</p>
  <span>four</span>
  <p>five</p>
  <h3>six</h3>
   
 </div>
```

just replace the 2 to a number of elements you want to select.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably how I would solve it, it might not be the best. Without using libraries

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('doc-container')[0].children).slice(0, 5))
```

```html
<div class="doc-container">
  <p>one</p>
  <h1>two</h1>
  <p>three</p>
  <span>four</span>
  <p>five</p>
  <h3>six</h3>
</div>
```